# Class template included in another Class template C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, data-structures

I am trying to program in C++ and I have a situation as following:

```
template<Class U>;
Class A<U>;
Class B;
```

and I need to do that code:

```
A<A<B>> x;
```

but I get the error:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
warning: >> operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++
```

I also tried :

```
A<(A<B>)> x;
```

But still doesn't work. How can I manage this ?

Comment: Don't post bogus code but a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Try `A<A<B> > x;`.

Comment: @Yaklefak It seems your compiler doesn't support C++11. Since C++11 the syntax should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
A<A<B>> x;
```

Should work, just add

```
-std=c++14
```

or

```
-std=c++11
```

To g++ flags, if you don't you have to write it with a space between the two >>